# How to return JSON object with one big array as just JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, spookyjs

We have a function in SpookyJS that returns a `JSON object` that contains just one huge `array` of `strings` when a GET method is called on it in `nodeJS`. We'd like it to return a `JSON object` with the `array` of `strings` converted to an `array` of `JSON objects`.

Note: We eventually want to be able to use these objects in `AngularJS` if that changes anything.

Here is the function:

```
res.send({reviewCount: reviews.length, reviews: reviews});
```

Here is what it returns:

```
{
    "reviewCount": 96,
    "reviews": [
        "\nSean Steinman\nreviewed 2 weeks ago\n Fantastic Service\n",
        "\nRyan Lundell\nreviewed in the last week\n Ask for Scott!\n• • •\n"
    ]
}
```

What we'd like to return:

```
{
    "reviewCount": 96,
    "reviews": [
        {name: "Sean Steinman", date: "reviewed 2 weeks ago", review: "Fantastic Service"},
        {name: "Ryan Lundell", date: "reviewed in the last week", review:"Ask for Scott!"}
    ]
}
```

We've tried to play around with `JSON.stringify()`, but it just converts everything into one JSON object:

```
res.send({reviewCount: reviews.length, reviews: JSON.stringify(reviews)});
```

Comment: Split on `\n` and manually add them to an object.

Comment: @BenFortune Awesome, would you like to add this as an answer with a little more detail?

Comment: You need to fix this at a lower level. Why isn't SpookifyJS doing any parsing of your data? It's probably coming across in divs that have semantic meaning baked into them. Use that to build your object rather than splitting on newlines.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann We're returning a drilled down ``outerText`` from the page being crawled, which is why it's returning it that way.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr: *that's* where you need to put your fix, then. `outerText` doesn't seem to be what you actually want, and you're making the consumer fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Here is what I did:

```
spooky.run(function(){
       var reviewObj = {
          reviewCount: reviews.length,
          reviews: []
        }
        reviews.forEach(function(line){   
          //turn the string into an array           
          var review = line.split('\n');
          });
          //add the array elements to the object
          reviewObj.reviews.push({name: review[0], date: review[1], reviewContent: review[2]});

        }); 

       this.echo('about to emit');
       this.emit("gotReviews", reviewObj);
    });
```